# How to run a complex command by xfce mail-watcher

Tags: command-line, bash, email, plugins, xfce-panel

I just installed the `xfce4-mailwatch-plugin`  I would like to use the option "Run on click" to either switch to Thunderbird, or to open it if it is not currently running. The command I use for this is `wmctrl -a thunderbird || thunderbird&`.

Since this is not working, I defined an alias for this command in `/etc/bash.bashrc`, but this does not have the effect I expected. The command works fine if launched from a shell, but launched by the mail-watcher this does not have any effect. However, just calling one of the two commands in question from the mail-watcher works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Aliases are specific to the shell and most likely xfce4-mailwatch-plugin knows nothing about them. That is why it isn't working for you.

The `||` and `&` are also shell-specific.

I suggest you create a 2-line script (the first line being #!/bin/sh) that does what needs to be done, save it and make it executable. Then configure xfce4-mailwatch-plugin to execute that script.